# deactivate notification on delivery failure in sendmail

Tags: linux, sendmail

How can I deactivate all delivery failure notifications in sendmail?

I have a internal testmachine hosting websites for testers. The sites use sendmail via PHP. Now whenever a tester enters a dummy address, I get a notification in my local mailbox. As this is an internal test machine, I'm not interested in any of those mails, and the notifications spam my box (had 28.000+ mails there).

Comment: this is a fundamental configuration change, please read the sendmail manual.or google it

Comment: Get rid of sendmail and use a proper testing MTA such as [fakemail](https://sourceforge.net/projects/fakemail/).

Comment: @MichaelHampton that is an incredibly useful thing to know about - thank you.  I think you should write it up as an actual answer, so I can upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set PostmasterCopy in your sendmail.cf?

```
grep PostmasterCopy /etc/mail/sendmail.cf
```

YES => You may turn it off

[confCOPY_ERRORS_TO PostmasterCopy](https://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/m4/tweaking_config.html#confCOPY_ERRORS_TO)

Answer (score 0):

Make sendmail at test machine capture/deliver outgoing mails to local mailbox/alias e.g. `capture`.

`sendmail.mc` line to capture ALL outgoing emails (sendmail.mc requires compilation into sendmail.cf):

```
define(`SMART_HOST',`local:capture')dnl
```

mailertable line to capture email to specific test domains:

```
example.com  local:capture1
example.net  local:capture2
example.org  local:capture3
# entry for sub-domains of example.org
.example.org local:capture3 
# entry for "all remaning domains"
.  local:capture
```